# Reverse Scrolling with xkb

Tags: xmodmap, xkb

Currently I'm using Xmodmap to reverse scrolling direction:

```
pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12
```

What is the equivalent way to do this with xkb? (or is this possible at all?) I'm evaluating KF5 and realise that Qt 5 doesn't respect xmodmap configuration.

Comment: Quiet old question, Just a hint if still looking, `libinput` handles such feature with current releases.